# Bean property init. from method call with property parameter

Tags: spring

I'm trying to find a way to initialize a Bean's Property by invoking a method that uses another Property as a parameter.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
<bean id="decoder" class="foo.Decoder" />
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Here I'm trying to call the do() method on a Decoder instance -->
    <!-- The application.dbUrl is defined in application.properties file -->
    <!-- ... can't find the right syntax. If any. Thanks! -->
    <property name="URL" value="#{decoder.do(application.dbUrl)}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<property name="URL" value="#{decoder.do('${application.dbUrl}')}" />
```

Notice the `${..}` which will instruct the SpEL parser to lookup it as property and not treat it as plain string value.

Let know in comments if any more information is required.

Comment: An `SpelEvaluationException`  is thrown saying that `...property cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext'`

Comment: I think it need the single quote as `'${...}'` in this case, please try with `<property name="URL" value="#{decoder.do('${application.dbUrl}')}" />` and let know results. I'll update the answer accordingly then.

Comment: Yep, it works with single quotes. I'll accept the answer after update.